# Run latexmk in background - only replace pdf when it is finished

Tags: latexmk

I have a pretty long latex document which takes more than a few seconds to compile. When using `latexmk -pvc` and I start scrolling the document, the whole pages turn blank as long as it is still compiling.

Is there a way to replace the main pdf file only after latexmk is finished? I would imagine a behavior of latexmk compiling into `help.pdf` and then copying the complete file to `main.pdf` after the compilation.

Comment: You could try (Unix shell syntax): `latexmk -pdf -jobname=help main.tex; mv help.pdf main.pdf`.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum that probably will not work with `-pvc` mode, it runs an infinite loop. Might be better to write the latexmk maintainer with a feature request

Comment: Maybe you can put the `mv help.pdf main.pdf` in `$pdf_update_command`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround (Linux syntax, but Windows would be very similar):

Write a custom `latexmkrc` file, for example called `refreshmc`, that defines the `$success_cmd` variable. This variabele is used to call a command whenever a `latexmk` run is completed. Copy the file to another file using this command, then open the other file in your PDF viewer. This ensures that the file being viewed is not modified until the end of the compilation.

latexmk can be run continuously without a viewer using `view=none`.

`refreshmc` file:

```perl
$success_cmd = 'cp %A.pdf tmpview.pdf';
```

latexmk call:

```
latexmk -r refreshmc -pvc -view=none yourfile.tex
```

Comment: A similar approach is used in [VimTeX](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex), when one `let`s `g:vimtex_view_use_temp_files` as `1` (see the [documentation](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/doc/vimtex.txt)).